# The parent content type specified by content type identifier [CT ID] does not exist

Tags: content-type

I try to deploy some solution and got this exception. In my solution I try to activate a feature which is creating a content type. this is the contenttype xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ContentType ID="0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D003CE876821EAC4EC8AAD81AC501EBCD07"
               Name="Intranet nieuws"
               Group="Intranet"
               Description="Een nieuws pagina voor Intranet nieuws."
               Inherits="TRUE"
               Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{0A54A9EB-549A-4060-9D9D-21DF838A6F1D}" Name="BPublishHomePage" />
      <FieldRef ID="{26922C2A-C2F7-4D4F-A189-E2B9C04418E2}" Name="BHomePageAuthorized" />
      <FieldRef ID="{088d0f9d-f41e-4859-9626-db2c010ae435}" Name="MMSCategoriesTaxHTField1" />
      <FieldRef ID="{1193AB83-78C9-4059-A6A9-48251639CA33}" Name="BNewsCategory" />
      <FieldRef ID="{cf8eab32-83ad-43a5-8e75-12d9005687ae}" Name="Nieuwslocatie"/>
    </FieldRefs>
  </ContentType>
</Elements>
```

Exception:

> The parent content type specified by content type identifier
>   0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D
>   does not exist.

what does this excepion means? Do I missing contenttype `0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D`  or the parent of `0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same problem when I try provisioning.

[image]

```
Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path C:/Provisioning/template.xml
```

You will be able to do the provisioning only if you have enabled the **SharePoint Server Publishing feature** in the Site Settings > Site Features.

Remember to enable the **SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure** under Site Settings > Site Collection Features before you enable the SharePoint Server Publishing feature in the Site Settings. It is a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

The contenttype ID you have in your XML is (trimmed for brevity) [...]26CD44D07. That references that it is a child of [...]26CD44D. If that content type does not exist on the site you're trying to load it to, it will fail.

Comment: how can I avoid this error. I would like to do some check if the publish feature is not activated do not activate this feature.

Comment: Google can help you with that. (Check for feature or check for column)

Answer (score 0):

you are specifying a contenttype in the xml which is inheriting from another, but the parent content type is not provisioned at that moment your feature is activated. see this msdn page for help understanding content type ids https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa543822%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

there a lot of ways to get a list of provisioned content types here is a powershell way: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.dk/2011/01/powershell-to-find-sharepoint-content.html

you can find the xml for most of the built in content types at your SharePoint server under the hive folder `TEMPLATE\FEATURES\ctypes\`